how to update some field value in sitecore using powershell?
I have got following script,
$newsPath = "/sitecore/content/XA/xa-website/home/News"
[Sitecore.Data.ID] $templateId = "{2A4C30D0-A53C-494F-AADF-3790828CDDFE}"

$news = Find-Item -Index `sitecore_master_index `
   -Where 'TemplateId = @0 and Path.StartsWith(@1)' `
   -WhereValues $templateId, $newsPath | Initialize-Item

$exportData = @()

foreach ($item in $news) {
    $nId = $item.ID
    $title = $item.Name
    $created = $item.Statistics.Created
    $changed = $item.Statistics.Updated
    $campus = $item.PsFields.'Campus'.value

    # Convert specific campus values
    switch ($campus) {
        "Abc" { $campus = "xyz" }
        "123" { $campus = "456" }
        "lmnop" { $campus = "qrst" }
        
    }

    # Create a hashtable to store the current item's data
    $itemData = [ordered]@{
        'Item ID' = $nId
        'Title' = $title
        'Created' = $created
        'Changed' = $changed
        'Campus' = $campus
    }

    # Add the current item's data to the exportData array
    $exportData += New-Object PSObject -Property $itemData
}

# Display the data as a table in the console
$exportData | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Display the total count of items
Write-Host "Total Items: $($exportData.Count)"

I want to update 'Campus' field in the item itself, these items are in bulk all created from {2A4C30D0-A53C-494F-AADF-3790828CDDFE} template
I know the switch statement i am using is updating the extracted data and displaying to console which is not what i want, I want it to actually update in the respective items.
Thanks in advance.

Have you tried:
$item.'Campus' = $campus


thanks this helps

To update the value of the "Campus" field in Sitecore, you need to modify the script to set the updated campus value back into the item and save the changes. Here's how you can modify your script:
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.'Campus' = $campus
$item.Editing.EndEdit()

This updated script will modify the "Campus" field in Sitecore items and save the changes.
Hope this helps.

thanks this helps
